# Can I make general statements about an Ito SDE without explicitly solving the kolmogorov forward or backward equations?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, conditional-probability, stochastic-differential-equations

I have an Ito SDE of the form

$$
dX_{t} = \mu(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dW_{t}
$$
that is, the mean and variance terms do not depend explicitly on time, and only on the position of the particle at each time point.

I want to examine the behaviour of this system without having to explicitly solve the Kolmogorov forward equation to find the density $p(x,t)$.  This is because for the functions $\mu$ and $\sigma$ I have considered to far, this is very difficult.  It is also because I would like to make statements about broad classes of functions.

My question is, if I state a family of functions $\mu$ and $\sigma$ for which I know they have some properties, then is it possible to do both of the following things

1. Given a final point of $X$, $x_{t}$, can i interogate whether $\mathbf{E}_{p(x_{t}\mid X_{0})}[X_{0}] = x_{t}$?  In other words, if I can write down a likelihood of a particle $x$ at time $t$ given all the possible starting locations $x_{0}$, can I find the expected started location, and is it equal to that given final location?
2. Given a starting point of $X$, $x_{0}$, can I interogate wether $\mathbf{E}_{p(X_{t}\mid x_{0})}[X_{t}] \neq x_{0}$?  In other words, if I can write down a conditional density of a particle $x$ at time $t$ given a fixed starting location $x_{0}$, can I find the expected end location, and is it different to the starting location?

I realise that in order to be able to do this, I probably need to make stronger assumptions on the functions $\mu(X_{t})$ and $\sigma(X_{t})$, but I don't really know what those assumptions might be, or if its worth trying to think about them if the problem I'm trying to solve has no chance of success.  Please advise.

Comment: The book *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus* by Karatzas and Shreve has a chapter *Connections [of SDEs] with Partial Differential Equations*. As far as I remember : they assume that $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are s.t. the PDE has a fundamental solution and then find a stochastic representation for it.